# loaddata raises IntegrityError when called within migration, but works if called from the CLI

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-fixtures, django-manage.py, loaddata

For my Django 1.8.12 site I have an `example_content` fixture which fills in some initial site content.

If I load this this right after running `migrate` it imports fine:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --noinput
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: ckeditor, staticfiles, zinnia_ckeditor, messages, djangocms_admin_style, webapp_creator, template_debug, sekizai, django_pygments, treebeard
  Apply all migrations: djangocms_inherit, djangocms_snippet, api_docs, cmsplugin_zinnia, sites, menus, contenttypes, store_data, zinnia, django_comments, sessions, rev
ersion, auth, djangocms_picture, tagging, developer_portal, admin, djangocms_link, djangocms_video, django_openid_auth, md_importer, cms, djangocms_text_ckeditor
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  ... (skipped for brevity).
  Applying django_comments.0003_add_submit_date_index... OK
$ ./manage.py loaddata example_content
Installed 139582 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
$
```

However, I'd like this data to import automatically on `migrate`, rather than requiring an extra manual `loaddata` step, so I'm trying to create a migration, `my_app.0002_example_content`, to call the `loaddata` command.

I'm making sure all the other data is loading first by adding dependencies on every relevant module.

To confirmed that this migration is indeed being run last (as it was when it succeeded above) I first commented out the `RunPython` step leaving the migration empty:

```
# my_app/migrations/0002_example_content.py

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    from django.core.management import call_command
    from django.db import models, migrations

    dependencies = [
        ('djangocms_inherit', '0002_auto_20150622_1244'),
        ... all other apps (skipped for brevity)
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [
#        migrations.RunPython(
#            lambda apps, schema_editor: call_command("loaddata", "example_content")
#        )
    ]
```

And sure enough it runs as the last migration:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --noinput
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: ckeditor, staticfiles, zinnia_ckeditor, messages, djangocms_admin_style, webapp_creator, template_debug, sekizai, django_pygments, treebeard
  Apply all migrations: djangocms_inherit, djangocms_snippet, api_docs, cmsplugin_zinnia, sites, menus, contenttypes, store_data, zinnia, django_comments, sessions, reversion, auth, djangocms_picture, tagging, developer_portal, admin, djangocms_link, djangocms_video, django_openid_auth, md_importer, cms, djangocms_text_ckeditor
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  ... (skipped for brevity)
  Applying django_comments.0003_add_submit_date_index... OK
  Applying my_app.0001_initial... OK
  Applying my_app.0002_example_content... OK
$
```

However when I try to run it to actually run the `loaddata` command (commenting the code back in), I get an error:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --noinput
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: ckeditor, staticfiles, zinnia_ckeditor, messages, djangocms_admin_style, webapp_creator, template_debug, sekizai, django_pygments, treebeard
  Apply all migrations: djangocms_inherit, djangocms_snippet, api_docs, cmsplugin_zinnia, sites, menus, contenttypes, store_data, zinnia, django_comments, sessions, reversion, auth, djangocms_picture, tagging, developer_portal, admin, djangocms_link, djangocms_video, django_openid_auth, md_importer, cms, djangocms_text_ckeditor
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  ... (skipped for brevity)
  Applying django_comments.0003_add_submit_date_index... OK
  Applying my_app.0001_initial... OK
  Applying my_app.0002_example_content...Traceback (most recent call last):
...
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: The row in table 'django_comments' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: django_comments.content
_type_id contains a value '37' that does not have a corresponding value in django_content_type.id.
```

Given that my new migration is definitely being run after everything else, the order should be exactly the same as when I called `loaddata` manually. So I don't understand why it would succeed when being called through the CLI but fail when being called through a migration.

Is there something that happens at the end of the `migrate` step which I'm missing which might explain the discrepancy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted by [knbk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448207/loaddata-raises-integrityerror-when-called-within-migration-but-works-if-called/37448567#37448567), I managed to solve this.

Initially I tried manually calling [`update_contenttypes`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py#L7), but that on its own didn't work. It turns out I need to actually call all the [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signals, as I guess they do more tidying up that's needed.

Here's the `my_app.0002_example_content` I ended up with:

```
# my_app/migrations/0002_example_content.py

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import migrations
from django.apps import apps
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate


def finish_previous_migrations(migrate_apps):
    """
    Explicitly run the post_migrate actions
    for all apps
    """

    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        post_migrate.send(
            sender=app_config,
            app_config=app_config
        )


def load_site_content(migrate_apps, schema_editor):
    """
    Load the website content fixture
    """

    finish_previous_migrations(migrate_apps)

    call_command("loaddata", "example_content")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('djangocms_inherit', '0002_auto_20150622_1244'),
        ... all other apps (skipped for brevity)
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_site_content)
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Django uses a `post_migrate` signal to create missing content types, so if this is your first time migrating on the current database, the content type won't exist until after the migration to load data has run.

You can manually create the content types you need in your migration. Django will detect the existing content types, and won't create any duplicates.

Note that the specific id of a content type may vary between databases. It may be better to dump the data using [natural foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-dumpdata--natural-foreign).

Comment: Ah that'll be it! Do you know if there's any way to manually create the all the content types in the same way that `post_migrate` would?

Comment: Django creates them using [`update_contenttypes()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py#L7).